# How to schedule a Docker container in GCP

Tags: docker, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have 5 tasks in my project that need to be run periodically. Some of these tasks are run on a daily basis, some on a weekly basis.

I try to containerize each task in a Docker image. Here is one illustrative example:

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:2.7.0
RUN mkdir /home/MyProject
COPY . /home/MyProject
WORKDIR /home/MyProject/M1/src/
RUN pip install pandas numpy
CMD ./task1.sh
```

There are a list of Python scripts that need to be run in the task1.sh file defined above. This is not a server application or anything similar, it will run the task1.sh, which will run all the python scripts defined in it one by one, and the entire process will be finished within minutes. And the same process is supposed to be repeated 24 hours later.

How can I schedule such Docker containers in GCP? Are there different ways of doing it? Which one is comparably simpler if there are multiple solutions?

I am not a dev-ops expert by any means. All examples in documentation I find are explained for server applications which are running all the time, not like my example where the image needs to be run just once periodically. This topic is quite daunting for a beginner in this domain like myself.

---

### ADDENDUM:

Looking at Google's documentation for cronjobs in GKE on the following page:
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cronjobs

I find the following cronjob.yaml file:

```
# cronjob.yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  concurrencyPolicy: Allow
  startingDeadlineSeconds: 100
  suspend: false
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 3
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox
            args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo "Hello, World!"
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

It is stated that `this cronjob  prints the current time and a string once every minute`.

But it is documented in a way with the assumption that you deeply understand what is going on on the page, in which case you would not need to read the documentation!

Let's say that I have my image that I would like it to be run once every day, and the name of my image - say - is **`my_image`**.

I *assume* that I am supposed to change the following part for my own image.

```
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox
            args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo "Hello, World!"
```

It is a total mystery what these names and arguments mean.

```
name: hello
```

I suppose it is just a user selected name and does not have any practical importance.

```
image: busybox
```

Is this `busybox` the base image? If not, what is that? It says NOTHING about what this busybox thing is and where it comes from!

```
args:
- /bin/sh
- -c
- date; echo "Hello, World!"
```

And based on the explanation on the page, this is the part that prints the date and the `"Hello, World!"` string to the screen.

Ok... So, how do I modify this template to create a cronjob out of my own image `my_image`? This documentation does not help at all!

Comment: The question might be better suited for [`devops.stackexchange.com`](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @danyL I can't find any information there how I can schedule a job for a docker container. Can Google Scheduler be used for such a purpose? I would really appreciate some guidance.

Comment: If it doesnt work for you then ill remove comment. I thought cloud scheduler + cloud run might be of interest. If that does not work then check GKE and cronjobs https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cronjobs

Comment: @danyL thank you for your comment. GKE cronjobs is seemingly doing what I am looking for. I will study it in more detail.

Comment: Instead of GKE, you can use your container on COmpute Engine and schedule them to run periodically: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/schedule-instance-start-stop

Comment: Was your problem solved or are you still facing any issue @edn?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere is your suggestion simpler to get going compared to setting up GKE based on your view?

Comment: You don't have to learn and maintain a GKE cluster. Use a COS image (very small, with few things installed, required almost not maintenance) and deploy your container on it. Schedule the Compute Engine directly in the console, or by API and that's all. Simpler? I think yes. Portable? Scalable? No.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I am slowly approaching the deployment phase of my project so I haven't started studying things in detail yet. But my project will need to be maintained for a long period of time so portability and each maintenance are important. Is it worth to put the time to learn Kubernetes? Do you have to be an expert to be able to use it in GCP? It is not my goal at all to be an expert in that field, is it a realistic expectation that you can use Kubernetes cronjobs without being an expert in that area?

Comment: Using Kubernetes is difficult. Hopefully, Cloud Providers offer solution like GKE where the most complex part are managed. You are only in charge of the nodes and the networking part. But, for me who isn't a network admin or a system admin, it's still too complex (or at least I don't like and don't want to do that). That's why, if your requirement are very standard, you can use GKE Autopilot. You have few to know about kubernetes, only the API (yaml definition of your jobs) and the scalability. That's roughly all and I recommend to start by that solution first.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Thank you for your feedback so far. I will then start with the GKE solution of Google. My use case should not be too complex, just a handful jobs needs to be run periodically. If I get your comment right, to make it work looks feasible without becoming an expert in the domain.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I added new information to my question above. Any chance that is something that you are knowledgeable about? I am totally stuck with this.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer your comment here, because the second part of your question is too long to answer.

Don't be afraid, it's kubernetes API definition. You declare what you want to the control plane. It is in charge to make your whishes happen!

```
# cronjob.yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1 # The API that you call
kind: CronJob # The type of object/endpoint in that API
metadata:
  name: hello # The name of your job definition
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *" # Your scheduling, change it to "0 10 * * *" to run your job every dat at 10.00am
  concurrencyPolicy: Allow # config stuff, deep dive later
  startingDeadlineSeconds: 100 # config stuff, deep dive later
  suspend: false # config stuff, deep dive later
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 3 # config stuff, deep dive later
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1 # config stuff, deep dive later
  jobTemplate: # Your execution definition
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello # Custom name of your container. Only to help you in case of debug, logs, ...
            image: busybox # Image of your container, can be gcr.io/projectID/myContainer for example
            args: # Args to pass to your container. You also have the "entrypoint" definition to change if you want. The entrypoint is the binary to run and that will receive the args
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo "Hello, World!"
# You can also use "command" to run the command with the args directly. In fact it's WHAT you start in your container to perform the job.
          restartPolicy: OnFailure # Config in case of failure.
```

You have more details on the API definition [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/)

[Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/workload-resources/pod-v1/#Container) the API definition of a container with all the possible values to customize it.

Comment: you are such a legend! This provides great information, especially the "API definition of a container" part. Now, I have my image locally on my computer. And in order to be able to create a cronjob in GKE, I guess I first need to push my local image to GKE by following guidelines here: cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/… Do I get it right? Also, may I assume that I first need to create a cluster in GKE to be able to run cronjobs?

Comment: Right. You can use the Container Registry (legacy version to store container) or Artifact registry (you can have containers, but also Java, Node, Python artifact in it, and it's easiest to share with other if needed. So, it's a newer version). And Yes, to use GKE you need a GKE cluster (standard or autopilot; I recommend to start testing autopilot)

Comment: Another info: Why Kubernetes and GKE? Here a video of the master: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ge5FbBILqm8

Comment: Great information! It makes it a lot easier to make a more concrete plan for studying. Thank you!